# NSS not working with Java 7 update 6

Tags: java, nss, pkcs#11

I was using jre6 with NSS (version 3.4.12) in my project and it was working fine.

I recently updated to jre7 update 6 (Released 2012 Aug 14th), and suddenly the application stopped working giving following exception.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetOperationState(J)[B
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_GetOperationState(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.clone(P11Digest.java:308)
    at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.clone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeHash.cloneDigest(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeHash.getMD5Clone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$Finished.getFinished(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$Finished.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
```

If i use jre 7 update 5, and its working fine !!!  I went through the release notes of update 6 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u6-relnotes-1729681.html and i cant find anything that might have caused..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When i compared java source code from update 5 to 6, i have found that in update 6, sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.P11Digest.java has newly implemented clone() which is trying to call native method PKCS11.C_GetOperationState which is also newly added in update 6. 

I dont know if they can add native methods just like that. Also i dont see any such mention in the update 6 revision history. 

To me it looks like PKCS11 interface is broken in jre7 update 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sun has fixed this issue.

Its scheduled for jre7 u9. https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7195931

Answer (score 0):

There were changes in [SunPKCS11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-7.html) for RSA in Java 7. But I am not sure that above behaviour is happening because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Bug https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7195931 opened on jre.